# Maybe too harsh throttling limit for the batch request?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Some of my customers are getting `HTTP 429` errors from [batch request](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/json_batching).

I'm sending `20` request in a batch request:

```json
{
  "requests": [
    { "id": "1", "url": "/users/xxxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx/drive", "method": "GET" },
    { "id": "2", "url": "/users//xxxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxy/drive", "method": "GET" }
    //...
  ]
}
```

Microsoft Graph returns an `HTTP 429` for some of the requests. For the normal HTTP requests (one by one), it returns the correct result.

Maybe the batch request has different logic for throttling limit?

Comment: How often are you queuing up a batch like this?

Comment: We use this for user discovery, and it does not happen frequently. The customer case they ran this in couple of hours. Some of them has more than 10k users some only have dozen (so only 1 batch request).

Comment: I believe OneDrive is throttled at 5 RPS which is likely why it's working serially by not as a batch. Is there any correlation between the number of users and when the `429` errors start?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no such relation btwn the # of users and the 429 errors. Even I have different results (sometimes succeeds sometimes don't) whenever I run the job in 10 minutes interval. Only thing I am suspecting is that they had EWS throttle situation from the same box where the grpah-api user discovery tool was running on.

Comment: Exchange and OneDrive handle throttling quite differently and they don't interact with each other. That said, if there is a substantial load on the tenant, it will start throttling across the board in order to prioritize interactive sessions (i.e. prioritize Word Online over OneDrive API calls).  My guess is that isn't happening here since the threshold for what constitutes a substantial load is pretty high.

Comment: It's important to note that you _should_ expect some `429` errors to crop up. This is why the documentation spesifically calls out the need to gracfully handle them. Obviously this is a bit trickier with batch jobs since you don't see them hitting until the batch is complete but the workflow is still the same, process the `429` returns and requeue for the next batch.